# Asymptotic variance

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence, parameter-estimation

$\text{Let}~(X_i)_{i=1}^n~ \text{be an i.i.d. sample of}$
$\text{n observations, with} ~ E(X_i)=\mu\in\mathbb{R}~ \text{and} ~ Var(X_i)=\sigma^2 \in (0, \infty)$

$\text{I'm asked to propose estimator}$
$\text{for the asymptotic variance of the}$ $\text{following distribution and to prove}$ 
$\text{that this estimator is consistent:}$ 
$\sqrt{n}\left(\ln \bar{X}_{n} - \ln \mu\right) \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{\mu^2})$

$\text{To do this, we have to use :}$ 
$\bar{X}_{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i} ~\text{and}$

$B_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^{2}-\bar{X}_{n}^2$

$\text{I tried but didn't get something}$

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not write everything in math mode. Math mode is for *math*, not all the text in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\bar{X}_n$ is an estimator of $\mu,$ $B_n$ is an estimator of $\sigma^2.$ A straightforward estimator for the asymptotic variance is then
$$V_n = B_n/(\bar{X}_n^2).$$

Are you able to show that $B_n$ and $\bar{X}_n$ are consistent estimators of $\sigma^2$ and $\mu$ respectively?

If we have this consistency, we have by the continuous mapping theorem that also $\bar{X}_n^2$ is consistent for $\mu^2$ and we can then complete the proof that $V_n$ is consistent for $\sigma^2/\mu^2$ by using Slutsky's lemma.

Comment: Yes, we can use Tchebychev inequality to prove that $\bar{X}_n \xrightarrow{p} \mu$. So $\bar{X}_n$ is a consistent estimator of $\mu$. Using this result and the weak law of large numbers, we can also prove that $B_n \xrightarrow{p} \sigma^2$. Is there any necessary condition for the proof to hold  ?

Comment: No, I don't see any further necessities. We require $\mu\neq 0$ of course, but otherwise the question does not even make much sense.

Comment: Is there others estimators?